# Cannot login through https://test.salesforce to the recently refreshed sandbox?

Tags: authentication, login-errors, mydomain, sandbox-refresh

I have deployed mydomain in the production. But after refreshed the sandbox I can't login through https://test.saelsforce.com. And Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com also unchecked. But I can login through the custom domain. Is there any other configurations needs to be done in order to activate test.salesforce on the sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After refreshed a sandbox it will take 24 hours to the new usernames to propagate to test.salesforce.com. Therefore if users cannot authenticate to the sandbox through test.salesforce.com better use instancename.salesforce.com url in order to login to the sandbox.

Thanks,
Prasad